# When in intellij, I am getting a warning in the syntax "Inconvertible Types: cannot cast ...", but no errors or warning in compilation

Tags: intellij-idea, syntax, java-7

Basically, I am seeing errors(warnings) in my project that should not be marked as errors in java 1.7. The code is compiling with no problem, so something must be wrong with the syntax highlighting. Initially I figured I was using java 1.6, but with further inspection, i was using java 1.7. I also noticed that this error did not show up as an issue when Inspecting code for the files the error occurs in.

I found this bug report: [intellij inconvertible types bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136527)

Does anyone know a fix for this?

For some background, I'm using Intellij IDEA version 15.0.1 and the project was imported from Maven

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is caused by an incorrectly configured *Project language level* in the Project Structure dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>on Windows, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> on the Mac). The language level can also be overridden in individual modules, so you may want to check the settings there too.

Comment: this is what I tried at first, but no luck... Thanks though